# Seagate 2TB HDD Not Showing up in BIOS

Tags: bios

I have a 2TB Seagate Barracuda HDD that a friend gave me to try and do some data restoration on but I am running into some strange issues.

First off, the drive still spins up when you apply power.   No unusual sounds are coming from the hard drive.   If I plug it into a Windows desktop, the hard drive shows up as a removable device (even though I have it plugged directly to my computer via SATA) that is unformatted.   I am not too sure why a regular HDD would show up as a removable device.

The next thing I noticed was when I restarted my computer with only his drive connected to my machine, it is not recognized in BIOS for some strange reason.   I loaded up Ubuntu Rescue on a USB drive and booted my computer into it. Here are the outputs of a few commands to give you an idea of what /dev looks like, etc...

**Mount command**

```
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sda1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

**ls /dev Output**

```
drwxr-xr-x 16 root   root        4280 May  3 14:29 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         260 May  3 14:29 ..
crw-rw----  1 root   video    10, 175 May  3 14:29 agpgart
crw------T  1 root   root     10, 235 May  3 14:29 autofs
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root         580 May  3 14:28 block
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root          80 May  3 14:28 bsg
crw------T  1 root   root     10, 234 May  3 14:29 btrfs-control
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root          60 May  3 14:27 bus
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root        4380 May  3 14:29 char
crw-------  1 root   root      5,   1 May  3 14:29 console
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          11 May  3 14:29 core -> /proc/kcore
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root          60 May  3 14:29 cpu
crw-------  1 root   root     10,  60 May  3 14:29 cpu_dma_latency
drwxr-xr-x  6 root   root         120 May  3 14:28 disk
crw-rw---T  1 root   audio    14,  41 May  3 14:29 dmmidi2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root          80 May  3 14:28 dri
crw-------  1 root   root     10,  61 May  3 14:29 ecryptfs
crw-rw----  1 root   video    29,   0 May  3 14:29 fb0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          13 May  3 14:29 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   root      1,   7 May  3 14:29 full
crw-rw-rwT  1 root   fuse     10, 229 May  3 14:29 fuse
crw-------  1 root   root    250,   0 May  3 14:29 fw0
crw-------  1 root   root    251,   0 May  3 14:29 hidraw0
crw-------  1 root   root    251,   1 May  3 14:29 hidraw1
crw-------  1 root   root    251,   2 May  3 14:29 hidraw2
crw-------  1 root   root    251,   3 May  3 14:29 hidraw3
crw-------  1 root   root    251,   4 May  3 14:29 hidraw4
crw-------  1 root   root    251,   5 May  3 14:29 hidraw5
crw-------  1 root   root    251,   6 May  3 14:29 hidraw6
crw-------  1 root   root     10, 228 May  3 14:29 hpet
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          14 May  3 14:28 .initramfs -> /run/initramfs
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root         460 May  3 14:29 input
crw-------  1 root   root      1,  11 May  3 14:29 kmsg
srw-rw-rw-  1 root   root           0 May  3 14:29 log
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      7,   0 May  3 14:29 loop0
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      7,   1 May  3 14:29 loop1
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      7,   2 May  3 14:29 loop2
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      7,   3 May  3 14:29 loop3
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      7,   4 May  3 14:29 loop4
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      7,   5 May  3 14:29 loop5
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      7,   6 May  3 14:29 loop6
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      7,   7 May  3 14:29 loop7
crw-------  1 root   root     10, 237 May  3 14:29 loop-control
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root          60 May  3 14:27 mapper
crw-------  1 root   root     10, 227 May  3 14:29 mcelog
crw-------  1 root   root    249,   1 May  3 14:29 mei
crw-r-----  1 root   kmem      1,   1 May  3 14:29 mem
crw-rw---T  1 root   audio    14,  34 May  3 14:29 midi2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root          60 May  3 14:27 net
crw-------  1 root   root     10,  59 May  3 14:29 network_latency
crw-------  1 root   root     10,  58 May  3 14:29 network_throughput
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   root      1,   3 May  3 14:29 null
crw-------  1 root   root      1,  12 May  3 14:29 oldmem
crw-r-----  1 root   kmem      1,   4 May  3 14:29 port
crw-------  1 root   root    108,   0 May  3 14:29 ppp
crw-------  1 root   root     10,   1 May  3 14:29 psaux
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   tty       5,   2 May  3 21:53 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root           0 May  3 14:27 pts
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,   0 May  3 14:29 ram0
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,   1 May  3 14:29 ram1
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,  10 May  3 14:29 ram10
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,  11 May  3 14:29 ram11
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,  12 May  3 14:29 ram12
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,  13 May  3 14:29 ram13
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,  14 May  3 14:29 ram14
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,  15 May  3 14:29 ram15
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,   2 May  3 14:29 ram2
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,   3 May  3 14:29 ram3
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,   4 May  3 14:29 ram4
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,   5 May  3 14:29 ram5
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,   6 May  3 14:29 ram6
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,   7 May  3 14:29 ram7
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,   8 May  3 14:29 ram8
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      1,   9 May  3 14:29 ram9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   root      1,   8 May  3 14:29 random
crw-r--r--  1 root   root     10,  62 May  3 14:29 rfkill
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root           4 May  3 14:29 rtc -> rtc0
crw-------  1 root   root    254,   0 May  3 14:29 rtc0
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      8,   0 May  3 14:29 sda
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      8,   1 May  3 14:29 sda1
brw-rw----  1 root   disk      8,  16 May  3 14:29 sdb
crw-rw----  1 root   disk     21,   0 May  3 14:29 sg0
crw-rw----  1 root   disk     21,   1 May  3 14:29 sg1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root           8 May  3 14:29 shm -> /run/shm
crw-------  1 root   root     10, 231 May  3 14:29 snapshot
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root         440 May  3 14:29 snd
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          15 May  3 14:29 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          15 May  3 14:29 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          15 May  3 14:29 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   tty       5,   0 May  3 21:48 tty
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,   0 May  3 14:29 tty0
crw-------  1 ubuntu tty       4,   1 May  3 21:47 tty1
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  10 May  3 14:29 tty10
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  11 May  3 14:29 tty11
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  12 May  3 14:29 tty12
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  13 May  3 14:29 tty13
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  14 May  3 14:29 tty14
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  15 May  3 14:29 tty15
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  16 May  3 14:29 tty16
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  17 May  3 14:29 tty17
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  18 May  3 14:29 tty18
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  19 May  3 14:29 tty19
crw-------  1 ubuntu tty       4,   2 May  3 21:33 tty2
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  20 May  3 14:29 tty20
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  21 May  3 14:29 tty21
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  22 May  3 14:29 tty22
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  23 May  3 14:29 tty23
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  24 May  3 14:29 tty24
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  25 May  3 14:29 tty25
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  26 May  3 14:29 tty26
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  27 May  3 14:29 tty27
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  28 May  3 14:29 tty28
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  29 May  3 14:29 tty29
crw-------  1 ubuntu tty       4,   3 May  3 21:48 tty3
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  30 May  3 14:29 tty30
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  31 May  3 14:29 tty31
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  32 May  3 14:29 tty32
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  33 May  3 14:29 tty33
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  34 May  3 14:29 tty34
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  35 May  3 14:29 tty35
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  36 May  3 14:29 tty36
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  37 May  3 14:29 tty37
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  38 May  3 14:29 tty38
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  39 May  3 14:29 tty39
crw-------  1 ubuntu tty       4,   4 May  3 14:29 tty4
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  40 May  3 14:29 tty40
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  41 May  3 14:29 tty41
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  42 May  3 14:29 tty42
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  43 May  3 14:29 tty43
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  44 May  3 14:29 tty44
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  45 May  3 14:29 tty45
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  46 May  3 14:29 tty46
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  47 May  3 14:29 tty47
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  48 May  3 14:29 tty48
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  49 May  3 14:29 tty49
crw-------  1 ubuntu tty       4,   5 May  3 14:29 tty5
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  50 May  3 14:29 tty50
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  51 May  3 14:29 tty51
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  52 May  3 14:29 tty52
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  53 May  3 14:29 tty53
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  54 May  3 14:29 tty54
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  55 May  3 14:29 tty55
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  56 May  3 14:29 tty56
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  57 May  3 14:29 tty57
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  58 May  3 14:29 tty58
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  59 May  3 14:29 tty59
crw-------  1 ubuntu tty       4,   6 May  3 14:29 tty6
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  60 May  3 14:29 tty60
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  61 May  3 14:29 tty61
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  62 May  3 14:29 tty62
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,  63 May  3 14:29 tty63
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,   7 May  3 14:29 tty7
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,   8 May  3 14:29 tty8
crw--w----  1 root   tty       4,   9 May  3 14:29 tty9
crw-------  1 root   root      5,   3 May  3 14:29 ttyprintk
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  64 May  3 14:29 ttyS0
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  65 May  3 14:29 ttyS1
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  74 May  3 14:29 ttyS10
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  75 May  3 14:29 ttyS11
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  76 May  3 14:29 ttyS12
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  77 May  3 14:29 ttyS13
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  78 May  3 14:29 ttyS14
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  79 May  3 14:29 ttyS15
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  80 May  3 14:29 ttyS16
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  81 May  3 14:29 ttyS17
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  82 May  3 14:29 ttyS18
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  83 May  3 14:29 ttyS19
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  66 May  3 14:29 ttyS2
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  84 May  3 14:29 ttyS20
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  85 May  3 14:29 ttyS21
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  86 May  3 14:29 ttyS22
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  87 May  3 14:29 ttyS23
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  88 May  3 14:29 ttyS24
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  89 May  3 14:29 ttyS25
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  90 May  3 14:29 ttyS26
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  91 May  3 14:29 ttyS27
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  92 May  3 14:29 ttyS28
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  93 May  3 14:29 ttyS29
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  67 May  3 14:29 ttyS3
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  94 May  3 14:29 ttyS30
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  95 May  3 14:29 ttyS31
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  68 May  3 14:29 ttyS4
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  69 May  3 14:29 ttyS5
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  70 May  3 14:29 ttyS6
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  71 May  3 14:29 ttyS7
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  72 May  3 14:29 ttyS8
crw-rw----  1 root   dialout   4,  73 May  3 14:29 ttyS9
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root          60 May  3 14:29 .udev
crw-r-----  1 root   root     10, 223 May  3 14:29 uinput
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   root      1,   9 May  3 14:29 urandom
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root         100 May  3 14:29 usb
crw-------  1 root   root    252,   0 May  3 14:29 usbmon0
crw-------  1 root   root    252,   1 May  3 14:29 usbmon1
crw-------  1 root   root    252,   2 May  3 14:29 usbmon2
crw-------  1 root   root    252,   3 May  3 14:29 usbmon3
crw-------  1 root   root    252,   4 May  3 14:29 usbmon4
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7,   0 May  3 14:29 vcs
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7,   1 May  3 14:29 vcs1
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7,   2 May  3 14:29 vcs2
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7,   3 May  3 14:29 vcs3
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7,   4 May  3 14:29 vcs4
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7,   5 May  3 14:29 vcs5
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7,   6 May  3 14:29 vcs6
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7,   7 May  3 14:29 vcs7
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7, 128 May  3 14:29 vcsa
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7, 129 May  3 14:29 vcsa1
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7, 130 May  3 14:29 vcsa2
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7, 131 May  3 14:29 vcsa3
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7, 132 May  3 14:29 vcsa4
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7, 133 May  3 14:29 vcsa5
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7, 134 May  3 14:29 vcsa6
crw-rw----  1 root   tty       7, 135 May  3 14:29 vcsa7
crw-------  1 root   root     10,  63 May  3 14:29 vga_arbiter
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   root      1,   5 May  3 14:29 zero
```

To tell you the truth, so far this Ubuntu Rescue distro has been very underwhelming.   I was hoping it would at least have a basic GUI (if it does, it did not load on my test machine that can load x windows without issues when I boot any other version of Ubuntu) so I could easily explore the tools it has available, but instead I was forced to install lynx and go browse the internet and read the documentation to figure out what tools were included in the distro.

Anyway, here are my question(s):

What would cause the drive to show up in Windows as a removable drive that is not formatted but the same drive does not seem to be recognized in BIOS?

I have a 2nd 2TB hard drive that I am prepared to use to copy the data to - but does anyone have any suggestions for hardware settings in BIOS (Motherboard is Intel DZ68DB)?

Any idea why a hard drive that is being connected via SATA would show up as a removable drive?

Can anyone suggest any software I should take a look @ to assist with this issue? I am very comfortable with Linux or Windows so tools for either platform would be fine.

Let me know if you need me to post the output of any other Linux commands on the machine I am using to attempt to restore the data on.

As a last resort, the 2nd 2TB HDD is the same exact model/make of HDD.   Anyone have luck swapping out the drive circuitry between two of the same exact drives?   I have a background in Electrical Engineering, but I have to admit I have never taken the PCB off of a drive and swapped it out with another one.   It seems like it might be possible, but I would rather not have to resort to such extreme measures.

The entire reason I am even involved in this situation is I guess there are pictures on this HDD of some deceased family members and this happens to be the only copy he has of this data.   I have already read him the riot act regarding doing regular offsite backups, but that does not do much to help resolve the situation at hand.

Any help would be great - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some SATA ports on the motherboard can be set to "ESATA" use, for hotplugging. This would make the drive seen as removable.

So, please check BIOS settings for the SATA ports (You'll probably need to get your motherboard manual) which describes which ports can be set for hotplugging.

Comment: Hmm, now that you mention it, the drive is currently hooked up to a dock on the top of my chassis.  I'll look into that and let you know if that is connected via esata.

Comment: that does not appear to be the  cause of this issue.   After further inspection, it appears that the HDD circuit board has some discoloration near one of the ICs, which is leading me to the conclusion that the board will need to be replaced.  Thanks for the suggestion tho.